# All cases when Solidity compiles to invalid jump destination

Tags: solidity, out-of-gas, compilation, solc

Solidity generates EVM bytecode that leads to an invalid jump destination when:

- `throw` is used
- ... ?
- ... ?

Can the above list be completed, with examples?

To explain the first item, `throw` in Solidity source code, gets compiled to EVM bytecode that leads to an invalid jump destination.  (Of course it assumes that the `throw` is not in dead code that might be optimized away.)  What are all the other scenarios that belong in the list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jumps to invalid jump destinations are generated only for (explicit or implicit) exceptions. An explicit exception is when you use the keyword `throw`. Implicit exceptions happen for runtime errors:

- array access out of bounds
- failed sub-call (due to any reason reported by the EVM including invalid jump dest in the sub-call)
- ether sent to a library fallback function

Comment: I'd add: sending ether to a function not defined as `payable`

Answer (score 7):

### Array Out Of Bounds

```
contract InvalidJump {
    uint[5] data;

    function invalidJump1() {
       uint i = 6000;
       data[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

And the message is from `debug.traceTransaction(...)` is:

```
error: "invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2"
```

### (Somewhat Related) Stack Limit Reached 1024

Not what was asked in the question, but interesting anyway.

```
contract InvalidJump2 {
    function invalidJump2(uint number) {
        invalidJump2(number - 1);
    }
}
```

Calling with the following transaction:

```
invalidJump.invalidJump2(1, eth.accounts[0], {
  from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
  data: invalidJumpCompiled.InvalidJump.code,
  gas: 1000000
});
```

And the error message:

```
I0607 18:04:49.978794 core/state_transition.go:258] VM call err: stack limit reached 1024 (1024)
```

Plus the `debug.traceTransaction(...)` sends the `geth console` screen crazy.